# Solve this integral by using cover up method in partial fractions

Tags: linear-algebra

new user here. I am trying to decompose the following fraction so that it can be solved easily.

$$\frac{3x-2}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{(x-2)^2}$$

General formula: 
$$\frac{px+q}{(x-a)^2} = \frac{A}{x-a} + \frac{B}{(x-a)^2}$$

I am able to find the value of A by simply equating it to p (the coefficient of x) but I'm having trouble determining B. On substituting x=2 in either of the denominators, $$(x-2)$$ or $$(x-2)^2$$ They become 0 resulting in an indeterminant form of the fraction. Please help me out.

Comment: The cover-up method applied here will only give you $B$. This is because $x-2$ is a repeated factor. You'll have to plug in another value of $x$ to find $A$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing is to clear all denominators, resulting in

$$px+q=A(x-a)+B.$$

Simply plugging in $x=a$ will tell you what $B$ is; to find $A$ you can either differentiate both sides and set $x=a$ or you can simply equate coefficients to begin with. Or you can use another test point other than $a$.

(To be a little bit pedantic, the equation is only known to hold for $x \neq a$, since the original equation only held for $x \neq a$, so the procedure being used to find $B$ is actually sending $x \to a$. But the result is the same.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am familiar with the methods you mentioned but for larger denominators with higher powers, expanding and equating to the coefficient on the LHS is quite a tedious process for me. Directly being able to determine the values of constants (A, B, C, ...) is what I'm looking for. I'm able to find the values of constants for other forms of fractions like $$\frac{px^2+qx+r}{(x-a)^2(x-b)} = \frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{(x-a)^2}+\frac{C}{x-b}$$ Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @FarhanS In the end the work is more or less preserved regardless of how you do it, to be perfectly honest. But I think the way you are going for is what I mentioned with derivatives: you can find the coefficient of $(x-a)^{-N}$ (the biggest one) by clearing denominators and plugging in $x=a$, you can find the next one (if there is one) by differentiating and plugging in $x=a$, and so on down to $(x-a)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The fast way to find $A$ and $B$ is this:

Remove the denominators multiplying both sides by $(x-2)^2$; you obtain
$$3x-2=A(x-2)+B.$$
Now, setting $x=2$ yields instantly $\;\color{red}4=A\cdot 0+B\color{red}{=B}$.

Next, identifying the leading coefficients of both sides yields $\color{red}{3=A}$, whence the decomposition
$$\frac{3x-2}{(x-2)^2}=\frac 3{x-2}+\frac 4{(x-2)^2}.$$

*Note*: of course, one may write $\; 3x-2=3(x-2)+6-2=3(x-2)+4$ and split the fraction in two, but the above method is more general.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{3x-2}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{A}{x-2} + \frac{B}{(x-2)^2}$$

If and only if

$3x-2 = A(x-2) + B$

If you take $x = 2 \implies B = 4$

Then $3x-2 = A(x-2) + 4$

If you take $x = 0 \implies A = 3$

Then

$$\frac{3x-2}{(x-2)^2} = \frac{3}{x-2} + \frac{4}{(x-2)^2}$$